# is there a way to extend a fxml controller

Tags: java, javafx

I am building an app and I want to put in every page in the app the text "hello" with the label that writes the name of the client that is connected now ,how can I do that ???
for example : if I am connected now, in the top of all the pages in the app I will see hello Nadeen

Answer (score 2):

Use composition, not inheritance.

Inheritance is the wrong concept to try to achieve something like this. Instead add create a parent layout for this and add functionality to display content in it.

Example:

```
public class ParentController {

    @FXML
    private StackPane container;

    public void setContent(Node content) {
        // replace old container content
        container.getChildren().setAll(content);
    }

    // code for setting the name...

}
```

```xml
<VBox>
    <children>
        <Label text="Nadeen"/>
        <StackPane fx:id="container" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
    <children>
</VBox>
```

This allows you to replace the content with the results of loading different fxml files.

```
ParentController controller = ...;
controller.setContent(someNode);
...
controller.setContent(someOtherNode);
```

Make sure you properly access the controller as described here:

[Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

You could also go with the custom component approach...